# Repeating Content - PHP includes? [SEO]

Tags: php, html, seo

I have quite large amount of the **same** content that needs to be repeated on all 28 product pages of a website that I am working on.

In terms of SEO, I know web sites like Google don't like this and just see this as duplicated content.

I thought using a `<?php include 'page.php' ?>` would resolve this but this just writes the text as HTML and therefore makes no impact meaning it would still be seen as duplicated content.

I know I can use `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` so that bots don't read these pages but if I was to do this, the only page it would be following is the homepage.

What would be the best way to get around this?

Is it possible to use the NOFOLLOW method for certain sections of the website?

Any suggestions on this would be very helpful!

Comment: Rethink why you need to have large and repeated content on 28 pages.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying that the pages are included duplicate times? Or that the same content exists in the files you are including?

Comment: Okay, I have one file.php that has around 600-1000 characters, that are currently repeated across all 28 product pages, it is a requirement from the client. Each product page at the moment has <?php include file.php ?>

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to think about your visitors first, not Google and their SEO requirements. Is the repetition of content beneficial to the visitors, then do it.

In SEO terms: if you duplicated content 28 times it might be seen as the same content, so it's not counted seperately. So what? It *IS* the same content, and you know it.

Websites are made for visitors in the first place, and search engines secondly. You should take SEO optimization in consideration, but don't let it dictate the user experience of your website. Make the best website you can, for real people.

Answer (score 1):

Google understands boilerplate content, so if you need the information on the pages, then so be it.

> Google is generally quite good at recognizing "boilerplate text" (text
>   which you repeat on many pages) and treating it appropriately. I
>   wouldn't worry about having to place a disclaimer on your pages. If
>   you want to make it clearer to search engines that it's not relevant
>   to your content, you could also just place the text in an image
>   (personally, I'd just place the text on the pages normally).

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-duplicate-text-14515.html

Comment: Hi there, that article was posted in 2011 and since the Panda update has come from Google this has caused big big issues in terms of duplicate content which has effected a couple of my websites

Comment: Panda doesnt target benign boilerplate content ! If you are in any doubt to that, get yourself in a Google Webmaster hangout and ask.

Answer (score -1):

There's a better way to do this.

Combine the 28 product pages into 1 page that serves dynamic content from a database.

So each time you go to this single page, you pass a particular product ID (through a query string parameter, form data, a cookie, or a SESSION variable).

So instead of:

- product_bicycle.php
- product_skateboard.php
- product_widget.php
- etc.

You could have:

- products.php?id=123
- products.php?id=234
- products.php?id=345
- etc.

If all your product information in stored in raw HTML files, you'd just have to put those into a MySQL database.  Create a table called products.  Put in it a column called something like "Product_ID" which would hold the values like "123", "234", and "345" shown above.  And put in another column like "Product_Details" which would hold the HTML of the product description.

When the page loads, you'd want PHP to do the following things:

1. Show the HTML for the page header, logo, navigation tabs, and other shared items.  (Use the PHP "echo" or "print" statement - or just include it in the raw HTML of the page.)
2. Use the $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, or $_REQUEST variables to get the product ID passed to the page.  For example, "$id = $_GET['id'];"
3. Do a SQL query to pull up the product record based on the ID.
4. Show the description of the product from the result set.